# Geometry challenge question

Tags: geometry

The cross section of a tunnel 
is a circular arc $CEF$, as shown in the diagram. 
Note that the horizontal line $FC$ is a chord, 
not a diameter.

[image]

The maximum height $|AE|$ 
of the tunnel is $10$ feet.

A vertical strut ($|BD|=9$ feet)
supports the roof of the tunnel 
from the point $B$, which is located at
$27$ feet along the ground from the side
($|BC|=27$).

Calculate the width $|FC|$ of the tunnel at ground level.

My first thought was Pythagoras 
to create simultaneous equations 
for two right angled triangles 
$ABE$ and $BCD$
(in the right hand half of the diagram), 
aiming to find the distance $|AB|$ 
between the two verticals.

However, I kept going round in circles 
and could not get away from the "solution" 
$|AB|+27=|AB|+27$. Specifically, I can't form a second equation, 
perhaps involving radius of the circle, 
in order to obtain a unique value 
for the distance $|AB|$ between the two vertical lines $AE$ and $BD$.
I also had a look using similar triangles, which also proved fruitless.

Comment: Note that the drawing is not to scale.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that diagram is not to scale. Thus, horizontal line is a chord, not a diameter. Specifically, I can't form a second equation, perhaps involving radius of the circle, in order to obtain a unique value for the distance between the two vertical lines.

Comment: Thanks, Yves and jtm....very helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: The answer is: "the width of the tunnel at ground level" is 80;
the radius of the circle is 85.

Comment: @Joel Reyes Noche: it is  to scale now.

Comment: @g.kov Honestly, I found the original image easier to read---not being to scale is fine, and the grid that you have put in the background makes it harder to see what is going on.  Also, I object to the substantial edits that you made to the text of the question.  It is kay to suggest that an asker make edits for clarity, but it is another matter entirely to unilaterally change the content of a question.  I am tempted to rollback your edits, but would prefer to wait for input from the original asker.

Comment: There is a special term for the height of the arc above the midpoint of the chord, [sagitta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) from the Latin for *arrow*.

Comment: @Xander Henderson: The edit was made exclusively as an attempt 
to help to reopen the question, 
since the answer was ready too late,
and the image in fact, illustrates the answer 
(cells can be counted). But I still think that 
named points and MathJax notation provide more clarity to the question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $D',E'$ be the second intersection points 
of the verticals $DB,EA$ with the circle.
Also, let $R$ be the radius of the circle
and $y=|AF|=|AC|$.

By the [intersecting chords theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem),
\begin{align} 
|EA|\cdot|AE'|&=|FA|\cdot|AC|
,\\
|DB|\cdot|BD'|&=|FB|\cdot|BC|
,
\end{align}
we have a system of the two equations in two 
unknowns, $R$ and $y$:

\begin{align} 
a(2R-a)&=y^2
,\\
b(2(R-a)+b)&=c(2y-c)
.
\end{align}

After excluding $R$ from this system, we have
a quadratic equation in $y$:

\begin{align} 
y^2-2\cdot\frac{ac}b\cdot y+a\left(\frac{c^2}b-a+b\right)&=0
\end{align}
with two roots:
\begin{align} 
y_{\pm}&=\frac{ac}b\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{ac}b\right)^2-a\left(\frac{c^2}b-a+b\right)}
.
\end{align}

Substitution of $a=10,\ b=9,\ c=27$ gives

\begin{align}
y_+&=40
,\\
y_-&=20
,
\end{align}

and since $y>27$ must hold,
the only suitable value is $y=y_+=40$.

Hence, the answer is $|CF|=2y=80$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the center be $(-y,0)$ and the rightmost point $(0,x)$.

We express that $(0,10), (x,0)$ and $(x-27,9)$ all belong to the circle:

$$(10+y)^2=x^2+y^2=(x-27)^2+(y+9)^2.$$

Then subtracting the last two terms,

$$-54x+27^2+18y+81=0$$

or

$$y=3x+45.$$

Finally,

$$(10+3x+45)^2=x^2+(3x+45)^2$$ and $$x=10\sqrt{19}+30.$$